# How to reload a variable defined by let

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

A `user` has many `comments`, so I would like to have a factory `user` with a `comment` associated to it (`user_with_comment`):

```
factory :user, class: User  do |t|
  ...
  factory :user_with_comment do |t|
    after(:create) do |user|
      FactoryGirl.create(:comment, user_id: user.id)
    end
end
```

It works fine... when I call `FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_comment)`, it creates the `user` and the related `comment` in my `test db`.

However, I'm facing some issues in the `controller_spec`:

Using `let` I have to reload the `user` to see the `comment`:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_comment) }
user.comments.size #=>0
user.reload
user.comments.size #=>1
```

One solution would be using `before(:each)`, but it will create `venda` and `comment` before each test:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_comment)
end
@user.comments.size #=>1
```

Or, I can reload the `user`before each test, but it will also hit the database:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_comment) }
before(:each) do
  user.reload
end
```

What is the best approach in this situation?

Comment: If it needs in one example.. then `let` is perfect. I think so.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

How about this?

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_comment).reload }
```

Comment: This won't work because the method is memoized. That `.reload` will only be run on first use.

Comment: That shouldn't matter (and is, in fact, preferable)--they only need to reload the user one time so that the comment created in the factory is present.

Though actually, a better approach would be to do this in the factory itself so that every time you use this factory in your test, you don't have to also remember to reload the user.

Answer (score -2):

This has to do with the fact that let is lazy-evaluated and the comment for your user factory is added after the user is created.

> Note that let is lazy-evaluated: it is not evaluated until the first time
>   the method it defines is invoked.

See the [RSpec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-9/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let)  on let and let!

Using let means the user created when you first use it in an example and thus the comment is created after that. You can use let! to create the user before each example to avoid the reload. This shouldn't negatively impact your tests if you're using the factory in all/most of the examples in the spec.

Comment: I know the reason of my problem, but your answer does not suggest any solution.... `let` will not load the `comment` because the comment is created after the `user`, so I have to reload it. I am looking for a way to reload it only once, not before each test

Comment: Hmm sorry about that! It seemed as if the issue stemmed from the use of `let`, hope that info is at least useful to someone. I'm digging a little deeper and trying to recreate. I think something else is wrong here because I created a simple `user`, `comment`, and associated factories per your example and the comment is actually there without a reload.